# Should I avoid cache in every php file I insert via require_once()?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm developing an application using PHP and MySQL.

I'm facing a doubt: My **dashboard.php** looks like this

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
?>

<?php
// Allow display PHP errors
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(~0);
?>

<?php
require_once("dir1/file1.php");
require_once("dir2/file2.php");
?>

...
...
...etc
```

Every time I go to **dashboard.php** the page will be fresh, I'm using **header()** so the page will never be cached by browsers or whatever.

I don't want **dashboard.php** caches the contents of **dir/file1.php** and **dir/file2.php**.

My question is: Should I write the same **headers()** I have on top in **dashboard.php** to **file1.php** and **file2.php** to avoid cache when **dashboard.php** adds those files?

Comment: you should add the pah denied on the robot.txt root of you ftp. more info here http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html

Comment: I'm not talking about robots or search engines scaning my site. I'm talking about cache but thanks headmax.

Comment: The header is an instruction for the web server.  Including the php files does not involve your web server.  Furthermore,  headers only need to be sent once-- but always before any other content.  So, the answer is no.

Comment: As a further note, you would get an error if you did put them in the above code, because there are spaces/line feeds between your ?> and <?php tags. Try it and see...

Comment: Sorry wrong form :(.